# Enforce same second level object type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to enforce having the same translation keys for every language with TypeScript.

```js
const useTranslation<T extends TranslationObject> = (translations: T) => {
 ​// do something
}

const translations = {
  en: {
    button: "Hello World"
  },
  de: {
    button: "Hallo Welt"
  },
} ​

const invalidTranslations = {
  en: {
    button: "Hello World"
  },
  de: {
    foo: "Hallo Welt"
  },
} ​
// this should work
useTranslation(translations)

// this should give me a type error because typeof invalidTranslations["en"] !== typeof invalidTranslations["de"]
useTranslation(invalidTranslations)
```

I just can't figure out how the `TranslationObject` type should look in order to enforce the same type of all `typeof translations[Language]`. This is what I have so far:

```js
const languages = ["de", "en"] as const;
type Language = typeof languages[number];
type Translation = { [key: string]: string | Translation };
type TranslationObject = { [K in Language]: Translation };
```

Note: I'd like to use TypeScript's inference for `useTranslation` and not explicitly provide any generic types. I do have a working example for providing the generic type:

```js
type UnionToIntersection<T> = (T extends any ? (k: T) => void : never) extends (k: infer I) => void ? I : never;
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? true : false;
type VerifyTranslations<T extends TranslationObject> = IsUnion<T[Language]> extends true ? T : never;

// "Argument of type '[...]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.ts(2345)"
useTranslation<VerifyTranslations<typeof invalidTranslations>>(invalidTranslations);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are 3 choices:

This will allow for any key

```
type Translation = {
    [x: string]: {
        button: string;
    }
}


/**
 * Any key is valid, but it will force the button property
 */
const translations: Translation = {
    "en": {
        button: ''
    }
}


const invalidTranslations: Translation = {
    "en": {
        button: ''
    }, 
    "es": {
        // Errors
        myCustomProp: ''
    }
}
```

These are options 2 and 3, giving you:

```
type SupportedLanguages = "en" | "es"
type Translations = {
    button: string;
    header: string;
}

type RequiredTranslation = {
    [x in SupportedLanguages]: {
        button: string;
        header: string;
    }
}


/**
 * This will require you to specify all of the keys found in 
 * SupportedLanguages, and will force you to specify all of 
 * the properties.
 */
const enhancedTranslations: RequiredTranslation= {
    "en": {
        button: "hello",
        header: "My header"
    },
    "es": {
        header: "Mi encabezado",
        button: "Mi botón"
    }
}

/**
 * Record will return a type similar to Translation above.
 */
type RecordSL = Record<SupportedLanguages, Translations>;
/**
 * By using Partial we tell TypeScript to make the properties 
 * optional.
 * 
 * This won't require any of them, but if they want to add one
 * then they will require to add the properties of the available 
 * translations
 */
type OptionRecord = Partial<RecordSL>


const optionalEnhancedTranslation: OptionRecord = {
    "en": {
        button: "My button",
        header: "My header"
    }
}
```

Edit (Added more to your original question):
If you want to pass your translation object as a method expression, you can just do this:

```
// No need for generics:
const useTranslation = (translations: OptionRecord) => {
    ​// do something
}
```

Edit x2 (Dec. 30)

I've been hitting my head for over an hour now. Can't crack the nut. Either someone more experienced in TypeScript will need to help you out, or check it at runtime, and throw an error if they don't match.

The problem is that TypeScript (AFAIK) will need to know something about your object so it can enforce it.

Now, if you do enforce one language, such as "en", then everything becomes easier:

```
type Languages = "en" | "es";

type En = typeof a["en"];
type Translate = Partial<Record<Languages, En>>;


const a = {
  en: {
    button: {},
  },
  es: {
    button: {},
  },
};

const b = {
  en: {
    button: {},
  },
};

const c = {
  en: {
    button: {},
  },
  es: {
    header: {},
  },
};

function getLanguages(language: Translate) {}

// OK
getLanguages(a);
// OK
getLanguages(b);
// Will throw
getLanguages(c);
```

Of course, that solution will also be problematic if you're trying to expose your function as a library, as it won't work.

Comment: Maybe I abstracted too much stuff away in my question: `useTranslation` is exposed by a library that doesn't know about the translation files that it gets. So it should accept any `TranslationObject` with first level keys being the supported languages (`"en" | "de"`) that share the same second level object type. The second level object type can, however, be totally arbitrary - it's just important that it's the same type for both `TranslationObject["en"]` and `TranslationObject["de"]`. So I cannot restrict the second level object type to e.g., `{ button: string }`

Comment: @CarleB.Navy do you think that the OptionRecord type written above would work for you? Why not expose the TranslationObject of the library? Does it not have any typings?

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't work for me because it defines the type of the translation object of each language (meaning, it needs to have a `button` and `header` key). Since that object is defined by the library's consumer, I cannot define it on the library side. I essentially need an object that looks like this `{ [K in Language]: Translation }` while `Translation` has this structure `{ [key: string]: string | Translation }`. The exact names of `keyof Translation` is arbitrary, but it needs to be the same for every language.

Comment: @CarleB.Navy So wait, you're telling me that you need a typing for an object with arbitrary keys that whichever the consumer places in one language, will also enforce it in the other language? But the caveat is that you don't know the keys beforehand, and you're trying to enforce a rule in which they are the same? (Please correct me)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it!

Comment: @CarleB.Navy Check my answer.

Comment: Thanks for putting in the effort, Jose! My goal is to write a plugin for i18next that uses TS to check that all the translation files are correct and no language specifies a translation that another doesn't specify. Because the plugin needs to be agnostic of the translations, I cannot specify the translation objects on the library side (as you outlined already). I guess I'll have to stick to the not so nice explicit generic declaration for now: `useTranslation<VerifyTranslations<typeof invalidTranslations>>(invalidTranslations);`
Thank you so much for your time anyway! :)

Comment: Hey Carle! No problem and Happy New Year! Glad to help out, especially for a great cause! Maybe another soul can come and help you out with that one. I'm also interested to see what could be the answer.